# How to create a category slider in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[image]

I want to create a slider as displayed in the image. Categories in the slider in header and below is the description for selected category.

Comment: by category slider? what is that exactly looking for? add a bit of code which you tried!

Comment: Hello, i need to display categories in header slider using ng-repeat, and on clicking on single category, its related products to be shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the categories in slider and on changing the category with left/right button you can get the index value of the item with which you can filter the product table where category id is saved.

So you just have to match the selected category id with the category id in products table.
Hope it will help you in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic `Segments` would be the best choice to implement this.  Check out [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/segment/Segment/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I followed the documentation and found that ion-segment is for Ionic2, and i am using ionic.